# How to add authentication using retrofit to api?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I'm using Imgur [API](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest) to fetch data, but this API needs authentication. I have used a retrofit library and I have client id for API. I'm very new and I don't have any idea how to add authentication using a retrofit. Please help me. Here is a tutorial but they are not using a retrofit [Tutorial](https://progur.com/2016/11/create-imgur-client-android.html).

**ApiClient.kt**

```
 package com.example.imgurapi.Network

import okhttp3.*
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import java.io.IOException

object ApiClient {
private var BASE_URL: String = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image/"
private var apiClient2: ApiClient? = null
private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

init {
    val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()

    //Create a new Interceptor.

    //Create a new Interceptor.
    val headerAuthorizationInterceptor: Interceptor = object : Interceptor {
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response? {
            var request: Request = chain.request()
            val headers: Headers =
                request.headers().newBuilder().add("Authorization", "01016a9fff88608").build()
            request = request.newBuilder().headers(headers).build()
            return chain.proceed(request)
        }
    }

    clientBuilder.addInterceptor(headerAuthorizationInterceptor)


    retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
}

fun getInstance(): ApiClient? {
    if (apiClient2 == null) {
        apiClient2 = ApiClient
    }
    return apiClient2
}

fun getApi(): ApiInterface? {
    return retrofit?.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
}
```

**ApiTerface.kt**

```
package com.example.imgurapi.Network


import ImageData
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Path

interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("image/{id}")
    open fun imageById(@Path("id") id: String?): Call<ImageData?>?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each client must register their application and receive the client_id and client_secret.

For public read-only and anonymous resources, such as getting image info, looking up user comments, etc. all you need to do is send an authorization header with your client_id in your requests. This also works if you'd like to upload images anonymously (without the image being tied to an account), or if you'd like to create an anonymous album. This lets us know which application is accessing the API.

Authorization: Client-ID YOUR_CLIENT_ID

For more info :
Flow the step by step instructions in

https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest